# Testing an activity 4 clicks deep using Robotium

Tags: robotium

I have a home activity ActivityA,  which has button that creates an intent,  sets up some Extras and calls ActivityB.  This in turn calls ActivityC ,  and in turn calls ActivityD.
I don't want to have to write a test case that opens ActivityA and proceeds to drill through 4 activities to get to the one I want to test.  How can I set up the Extras required by ActivityD when it launches to prevent errors in my code.  For example before I call the intent that launches activityD it sets up an Extra which ActivityD then uses.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robotium gives you an option to launch an activity with a given intent, you will need to determine the intent that you need in order to launch the activity correctly. If you look in logcat it might give you the details that you need to launch the activity correctly. If you are unsure what to look for post the logcat logs of the time between clicking the element on Activity C and Activity D launching and i can try to look for you.